# How to prevent React from re-rendering a whole component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

How can I prevent the camera from re-rendering every time a classification is set on the State?
Re-rendering the whole component causes a black screen for half-second, as shown below. I want just the text to update, is it possible? Or should I make a separate component?
I've seen React.memo() might be a solution, but couldn't make it work

[image]

Can anyone help me to work this around?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as mobilenet from '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet';
import {cameraWithTensors} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
console.disableYellowBox = true;

  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default function App() {


  const [classification, setClassification] = useState('');
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [mobilenetModel, setMobilenetModel] = useState(null);
  const [frameworkReady, setFrameworkReady] = useState(false);

  const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

  let requestAnimationFrameId = 0;

  const textureDims = Platform.OS === "ios"? { width: 1080, height: 1920 } : { width: 1600, height: 1200 };
  const tensorDims = { width: 224, height: 224 }; 


  useEffect(() => {
    if(!frameworkReady) {
      (async () => {

        //check permissions
        const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
        console.log(`permissions status: ${status}`);
        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');

        //we must always wait for the Tensorflow API to be ready before any TF operation...
        await tf.ready();

        //load the mobilenet model and save it in state
        setMobilenetModel(await loadMobileNetModel());

        setFrameworkReady(true);
      })();
    }
  }, []);



  const loadMobileNetModel = async () => {
    const model = await mobilenet.load();
    return model;
  }



  const getPrediction = async(tensor) => {
    if(!tensor) { return; }
    const prediction = await mobilenetModel.classify(tensor, 1);
 

    if(!prediction || prediction.length === 0) { return; }
    
    if(prediction[0].probability > 0.6) {

      setClassification(prediction[0].className);
    }
  }

  
  const handleCameraStream = (imageAsTensors) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor =  imageAsTensors.next().value;
      await getPrediction(nextImageTensor);
     
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
    };
    loop();
  }


  // Helper function to show the Camera View. 
  const renderCameraView = () => {
    return <View style={styles.cameraView}>
                <TensorCamera
                  style={styles.camera}
                  type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
                  zoom={0}
                  cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
                  cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
                  resizeHeight={tensorDims.height}
                  resizeWidth={tensorDims.width}
                  resizeDepth={3}
                  onReady={(imageAsTensors) => handleCameraStream(imageAsTensors)}
                  autorender={true}
                />
            </View>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {renderCameraView()} 
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          {classification}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    height: 100,
    bottom: -700,
  },
  title: {
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#ffffff'
  },
  cameraView: {
    flex:1,
   
  },
  camera : {
    width: windowWidth,
    height: windowHeight,
  },
});
```

Comment: Maybe trying to call useState only one time useState({classification:'',otherState:null}) and setState({...state,classification:'changeValue'})

Answer (score 1):

Create two child component, one for the camera and another for your text.

Use [context](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-in-5-minutes/) to store your classification state, then when you change the state of classification in your context, only the consumer of your classification state (text component child) will be changed.